# Cannot resolve method setAvailableProviders and Cannot resolve symbol IdpConfig

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am trying to add FirebaseUI Authentication in my app but I am badly stuck with it. I have added facebook, twitter and phone number verification in my app but it is giving me the error: `Cannot resolve method setAvailableProviders` and `Cannot resolve symbol IdpConfig`. What should I do in my app to overcome this error? You can see in the image that I have errors and red lines.

here is my manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.anonymous.userlogin">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

</manifest>
```

here is my gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.anonymous.userlogin"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    //android authentication dependicies.
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    //android login with fb tw ph user nterface dependices

    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.6.0'
    //compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.0.0'
    //facebook dependicies
   compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.27.0'
    //twitter dependicies
    compile("com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.0.0@aar") { transitive = true }
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '26.0.0-alpha1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is the code of my main activity

```
package com.example.anonymous.userlogin;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 123;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null)
           {}
        else
            {
            // not signed in
                startActivityForResult(
                        AuthUI.getInstance()
                                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                .setAvailableProviders(
                                        Arrays.asList(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build(),
                                                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.PHONE_VERIFICATION_PROVIDER).build(),
                                                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build(),
                                                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER).build(),
                                                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.TWITTER_PROVIDER).build()))
                                .build(),
                        RC_SIGN_IN);




           }
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the flagged errors:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using version 0.6.0 of FirebaseUI Auth (`com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth`) which does not have this functionality. You should be using version 2.x or 3.x instead.

In your app's `build.gradle` file change this:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.6.0'
//compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.0.0'
```

To this:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

change the dependency version from this:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.6.0'
```

to this:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.1'
```

and sync your project